# Is it possible to swap RR trent 900 engines to GP 7200 for existing A380 air frame?

Tags: aircraft-design, engine, multi-engine, airframe-and-powerplant

If an A380 was originally equiped with RR trent 900 engines, but decided to switch to GP 7200 for any reason, would this be possible? Has this kind of engine swap (different manufacturer engine swap) been done before?